# Calling mehtod from another form / user control nothing is happening while on parent form its working

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a parent form that loads different user controls but when I am trying to access a method on the parent form from a button on the user controller which is not working but if the same method is accessed from the own parent form its all good I excluded the rest of code and here is the code not working

method on Parent Form:

```
using IT_HUB_MANAGEMENT_SOLUTION.SERVICES;

namespace IT_HUB_MANAGEMENT_SOLUTION.APP_FORMS
{
    public partial class FIRST_RUN_FRM : Form
    {
        public FIRST_RUN_FRM()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

 public void NEXT_STEP_CMD()
        {
            MAIN_PANEL.Controls.Clear();
            FIRST_RUN_OBJECTS.CRYSTAL_REPORTS_CONTROL cRYSTAL_REPORTS_CONTROL = new();
            cRYSTAL_REPORTS_CONTROL.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            MAIN_PANEL.Controls.Add(cRYSTAL_REPORTS_CONTROL);
        }
}
```

here is the code on user controls:

```
public partial class DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL : UserControl 
    {       

        public DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    }
 private void NEXT_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FIRST_RUN_FRM fff = new();
            fff.NEXT_STEP_CMD();
        }
}
```

Comment: `and here is the code not working` have you tried settings breakpoints and stepping through your code?

Comment: yes i tried as i mentioned it is working when called from ```FIRST_RUN_FRM``` form but when I try to call the same method from ```DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL``` usercontrol its doing nothing at all neither error neither working

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal replicable example so we could further help?

Comment: How do you expect it to work when you're creating a new instance of that form and calling that new instance's function? What is your expected output ? This will never work like this... On another note, it's not normal for the user control to call a function on the parent form.. it's better to use an event probably

Comment: actually i have a main form which have 4 steps where each step checks for dot net frame work , 2 Mysql server, 3 my phone explorer and so on, so each step is made on separate usercontrol , what I want is now when downloading and installing is done so I can remove the current controller and load the other user controller, now here is the issue that i am not able to do from usercontrols form but it works on the Parent form

i am new to C# have good experience on vb.net so please provide a solution

Comment: can you provide me abit more details on how to use an event for this Dear Paul karam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not a normal behavior (at least for me) that a `UserControl` calls a parent form method directly. Usually user controls are not aware of the parent that is using them, and for me, it's a really smelly code.

In your code:

```
public partial class DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL : UserControl 
{       
    public DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void NEXT_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FIRST_RUN_FRM fff = new();
        fff.NEXT_STEP_CMD();
    }
}
```

You're simply creating a new instance of the `FIRST_RUN_FORM` (Also try to follow the naming convention) and then calling it's function. This won't throw a compiler error since it's a valid .Net syntax. You're creating a new class and calling a public function inside it. However, it won't show anything on your initial form because it's not the same instance.

There's two ways to fix this code, and I don't like the first way I'll show you.

1. You can add the parent form instance to the user control and pass it on when creating a new instance of the UC. Something like this:

   ```
    public partial class DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL : UserControl 
    {
        private FIRST_RUN_FRM _parent = null;

        public DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL(FIRST_RUN_FRM parent)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _parent = parent;
        }

        private void NEXT_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_parent == null) 
            {
                return;
            }

            _parent.NEXT_STEP_CMD(); //This might throw an error not related to this question
        }
    }
   ```

I wouldn't recommend this though.

What I'd go for is using events, this way you don't need the `UserControl` to know who their parent is or what should be done to the parent when a button inside the UC is clicked.

2. Event:

In the user control:

```
public partial class DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL : UserControl 
{
    public event EventHandler NextButtonClicked;
    
    public DOTNET_INSTALLER_CONTROL(FIRST_RUN_FRM parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _parent = parent;
    }
    
    private void NEXT_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnNextButtonClicked();
    }
    
    protected virtual void OnNextButtonClicked()
    {
        EventHandler handler = NextButtonClicked;
        handler?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

And in the parent form you'll subscribe to this event and react when it's fired.

Comment: i feel ashamed but can you provide the subscriber code for my parent form as I tried to research for event handling that made me even more  confused

Comment: sending parent form as parameter actually working for me but I want to understand the event handler as you told me you don't recommend working that way

Comment: It would be better to ask another question regarding this particular request. It's not a good practice to keep editing and modifying previous question/answer.

Comment: But I want to clarify one thing first even if we raise an event still we need to pass the parent form as a parameter so then what's the point of creating an event what you told me in your first part of the answer isn't it enough?